# PHP4 and sybase_ct on Novell SuSe 10.2

Tags: linux, php, sles, novell, sybase

Am migrating an existing Ubuntu8.04 server running PHP4 and the sybase_ct driver to SuSe 10.2

The trouble is the sybase_ct driver that I need to connect to our MSSQL2000 / 2005 database.

On the Ubuntu install I found a package on http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian etch main

which installed PHP4 and the sybase_ct driver.

However on the new SuSe install I'm having to compile PHP4 from source (all good), however the install of Sybase ASE is looking tricky, and unnecessary??

Is there an easy way to install PHP4 on SuSe... or an easy to get sybase_ct??

Many thanks

nzs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the openSuSe build service?

One of the things Novell got in buying SuSE was the AutoBuild process.  They extended it beyond just building the SuSE OS builds to also building packages across stacks of other platforms.

I was trying to find out how big the cluster that does the AutoBuild process is, and was told it was approaching 100 devices now.

AutoBuild service is at:  http://software.opensuse.org/search

Doing a quick search on sybase_ct did not return anything, but sybase returns 15 hits, mostly mono related.  But I am not sure what exactly you are looking for.

Take a look, it can be quite helpful.

Comment: Many thanks Geoff..  We decided after this roadblock to go to planB.  This involved basically snapshotting my current Ubuntu8.02 build and running that.  Cheers..